# PyGame exceptions and freezes when trying to render to window

Tags: python, pygame

Can someone tell me what's wrong with this Python code? I'm using Python 3.8.2.

This code is from the book Python Crash Course, 2nd Edition: A Hands-On, Project-Based Introduction to Programming. The original code uses `pygame.display.flip()` instead of `pygame.display.update()`, the original code will produce this error code: `pygame.error: Window surface is invalid, please call SDL_GetWindowSurface() to get a new surface`

However, after I changed it to `pygame.display.update()`, it just freezes my PC with blank PyGame window.

```
import pygame

from settings import Settings
from ship import Ship

class AlienInvasion:
    """ overall class to manage game assets and behavior."""

    def __init__(self):
        """Initialize the game, and create game resources."""
        pygame.init()
        self.settings = Settings()

        self.screen = pygame.display.set_mode((0, 0), pygame.FULLSCREEN)
        self.settings.screen_width = self.screen.get_rect().width
        self.settings.screen_height = self.screen.get_rect().height
        pygame.display.set_caption("Alien Invasion")

        self.ship = Ship(self)

    def run_game(self):
        """Start the main loop for the game."""
        while True:
            self._check_events()
            self.ship.update()
            self._update_screen()

    def _check_events(self):
        """respond to keyboard and mouse events."""
        for event in pygame.event.get():
            if event.type == pygame.QUIT:
                sys.exit()
            elif event.type == pygame.KEYDOWN:
                self._check_keydown_events(event)
            elif event.type == pygame.KEYUP:
                self._check_keyup_events(event)
            elif event.type == pygame.K_q:
                sys.exit()

    def _check_keydown_events(self, event):
        """Respond to keypresses."""
        if event.key == pygame.K_RIGHT:
            self.ship.moving_right = True
        if event.key == pygame.K_LEFT:
            self.ship.moving_left = True
        if event.key == pygame.K_UP:
            self.ship.moving_up = True
        if event.key == pygame.K_DOWN:
            self.ship.moving_down = True

    def _check_keyup_events(self, event):
        """Respond to key releases."""
        if event.key == pygame.K_RIGHT:
            self.ship.moving_right = False
        if event.key == pygame.K_LEFT:
            self.ship.moving_left = False
        if event.key == pygame.K_UP:
            self.ship.moving_up = False
        if event.key == pygame.K_DOWN:
            self.ship.moving_down = False

    def _update_screen(self):
        """Update images on the screen, and flip to the new screen."""
        self.screen.fill(self.settings.bg_color)
        self.ship.blitme()

        pygame.display.update()

if __name__ == '__main__':
    #make a game instance, and run the game.
    ai = AlienInvasion()
    ai.run_game()
```

Comment: The pygame [documentation](https://www.pygame.org/docs/ref/display.html#pygame.display.flip) might be useful

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You typed the program in incorrectly.  I found the source code for the entire book at https://github.com/ehmatthes/pcc_2e and this particular example is https://github.com/ehmatthes/pcc_2e/blob/master/chapter_12/piloting_the_ship/alien_invasion.py

Your program runs the same way for me - I get a blank frozen screen too.  As shown above, your program is ignoring the `pygame.K_q` keypress because you entered that line of code in the `_check_events()` function, instead of `_check_keydown_events()`.  That's what's making it seem like your computer is frozen.

The author's source code on github (linked above) runs fine for me.  I recommend you download or copy/paste that code instead of trying to type it in by hand.

Comment: I copied the whole code and run it. But it still doesn't work and the same error code came out : pygame.error: Window surface is invalid, please call SDL_GetWindowSurface() to get a new surface

Comment: By the way, the code works fine if I don't use pygame.FULLSCREEN

Comment: Ah darn.  I have Python version 3.6.9 and pygame version 1.9.6.  You can find out what you have with the commands `python --version` and `pip show pygame`.

Comment: I have pygame 2.0.0.dev6, SDL 2.0.10, python 3.8.2

Comment: Seems you might be chasing a bug in pygame.  I noticed from reading [one such bug report](https://github.com/pygame/pygame/issues/555]) that there is an example program you can use to reproduce and report the bug: `$ python -m pygame.examples.aliens`  Press the `f` key to toggle in and out of fullscreen mode.  If that reproduces the bug, then you can submit a bug report.